# AITOC Error for Inventory

Tags: magento, inventory

I'm getting an error when trying to mark my products in stock:

inventory -> Manage stock -> change from no to yes -> save =

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '4477-1-0' for key 'IDX_AITOC_STOCK_PRODUCT_WEBSITE', query was:
>   INSERT INTO 'aitoc_cataloginventory_stock_item' ('product_id',
>   'stock_id', 'qty', 'is_in_stock', 'use_config_manage_stock',
>   'use_config_qty_increments', 'qty_increments',
>   'use_config_enable_qty_increments', 'enable_qty_increments',
>   'is_decimal_divided') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

I've asked my Magento developer and they were unable to help.  I've googled and reached out to aitoc.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is paid extension seems which you bought from aitoc team, check with them also post same question here also : https://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I apologize, I did reach out to them and no response - so I'm doing my best to find an answer.  I will close this ticket.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to name the precise reason right away. As we mentioned in your support ticket there are several possible reasons for that:

1. Incorrect data in the stock table
2. Conflict with another extension that also pulls the stock data due to which our algorithm is trying to run several times
3. The outdated version of our extension is incompatible with the current Magento version
4. Incorrect set up of our extension that causes the creation of duplicate records (less probable but still)

Please reach out to us via the ticket system if we've left something unclear or you have more questions.